# ExpressionEngine 2.2.2: path.php doesn't exist?

Tags: php, expressionengine

I have a problem for create a multi language site with EE 2.2.2 because I don't have path.php, only admin.php and index.php, what does it mean?

(It is possible whether it is because of my version of EE, I've got the 2.2.2)

I can't use the extension for do that because of this.

Thank you in advance for all;

Best wishes, seb.

---

Thank you very much for answer me, rjb

I had watched the links you had post, but I have others question:

Do I also have to put a copy of the file admin.php in each of my directory of language, or the index.php file is sufficient to him only?...

Knowing that for the moment I am always on a local server, do I have to make rise of a level the admin.php file?

Furthermore, the file core.language.php was reappointed because I don't find it under this naming, what prevents me from protecting it, under what name does it exist under this version of EE?

Still thank you for the time which you granted and which you grant to my problems.

Best wishes, seb.

(I apologize for my English which is so bad, I'm sorry to be french, lol)

---

Hello,

The only files which can correspond are EE_Lang.php which is in

```
C:\wamp\www\ExpressionEngine2.2.2\system\expressionengine\core
```

and Lang.php which is in

```
C:\wamp\www\ExpressionEngine2.2.2\system\codeigniter\system\core.
```

Comment: Is the Add-On Extension built for EE1 or EE2? What's the actual error message you receive? Are you following instructions in the [EE Wiki](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/)?

Comment: at the base it built for EE 1, and i haven't got error message because i don't want to loose  a part or all my site or other. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine 1.x used `path.php` for setting [Manually Configurable Global Variables](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/templates/globals/pathphp_globals.html), which many **MultiLingual Approaches** used for localizing content thru the use of URL segment variables and specifically-named custom fields. <sup>[ [1](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site/), [2](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/) ]</sup>

With the rewrite of ExpressionEngine 2.x to use the [CodeIgniter Framework](http://codeigniter.com/), EllisLab merged the files `path.php` and `index.php` in the root directory into a single file: `index.php`.

```
/public_html
    – admin.php
    – index.php
    + images
    + system
    + themes
```

Starting with the release of EE 2.2.0 ([changelog](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/changelog.html#v220)), saw the introduction of a new file `admin.php` in the root directory, used as a placeholder for [Masking Access to the Control Panel](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/best_practices.html).